# Prevent ConEMU from closing tab after last program exits

Tags: windows-xp, batch, batch-file, conemu

What I want is some way to click on ANY batch file from Explorer and see the output without writing a helper script to `PAUSE` it afterwards.

---

This is a question which seems likely to generate more OT answers than it should (judging by similar questions people have asked). To minimize that I've created a short list of questions I'm not asking:

- [First](https://superuser.com/questions/676644/how-to-prevent-programs-from-closing-after-batch-file-is-executed), I **DO NOT** want to know how to use the `PAUSE` command or anything like it. 
  I'm not looking for a way to modify every batch file on my system now and into the 
  future.
- [Second](https://superuser.com/questions/731993/how-to-close-conemus-tab-without-confirmation), I **DO NOT** want to enable the `Confirm tab closing` option in ConEMU.
  By experimentation, I've found that this option does not seem to apply to batch files
  ran by clicking on them anyway.
- [Third](https://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution), I **DO NOT** want to modify the way batch files are handled by programs other
  than ConEMU. I don't want to create a situation where scripts ran in a non interactive
  shell are stalled and left open. IOW, I need to ensure that other applications which
  launch batch files are handled normally. I only want to modify how they are handled
  when clicked in an interactive shell.

Some things I've tried:

- ConEmu does apparently support logging (in the `Features` section) of the console. This 
  is great but it is really only a backup plan. I'd rather not have to open another file to 
  show me what was *just* on my screen for 0.1 sec.
- ConEmu has an `App Distinct` section in it's settings which looks like it could almost be
  setup to handle `*.bat` files using special rules but I cannot see anything which allows
  what I need.
- ConEmu has an `ComSpec` section in it's settings which looks like it could do this as 
  well (using `cmd.exe /k` I presume) but nothing I've tried has had any effect on this and 
  now I'm starting to think that all of those notes in the tool tips about what those 
  options are specific to were serious (and so this will therefore never work for what I 
  need now).

---

**Bonus**: If your solution will work with arbitrary exes as well that would be even better.

**PS**: Not sure why there are separate `Batch` and `Batch-File` tags. I've got space so I'll use both but someone may want to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> click on ANY batch file and see the output

Click where? Have you enabled [DefaultTerminal](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/DefaultTerminal) feature? It has a confirm option.

[image: DefTerm options]

Comment: I would like to be able to click the icon in Explorer to do this. Yes, I have enabled the Default Terminal option. I have also enabled 'Aggressive Mode' and 'Register on OS start up' and 'Use existing ...' options. The text box has 'explorer.exe' and everything else on that page is disabled.

Comment: "Everything else" is enabled of course as on screenshot.

Comment: That did it of course. Thanks. Not sure how I missed that. Even after you had me look at the setting page it didn't click.